# Match zero or more times not working properly for zero matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the URL and link text from these 2 types of URLs:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com" rel="nofollow">Example</a>
```

At first I had this:

```
text = text.replace(/<a href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a>/gim, "[$2]($1)");
```

But that includes `rel="nofollow"` in `$2` for the 2nd example. I changed it to:

```
text = text.replace(/<a href="(.*)"( rel=".*"{0,})>(.*)<\/a>/gim, "[$3]($1)");
```

Now, the `rel="nofollow"` link is perfect, but the first example isn't matched at all.

`{0,}` should mean "match `rel=".*"` 0 or more times".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think you should use jQuery or something like this, rather than rewriting a DOM parser...

Comment: @pataluc jQuery is seriously overkill for something as simple as this. I know the format of the URLs is either one of the two examples. It won't contain any other attributes.

Comment: I assume that giving your example you'll have further use of jQuery... ^^ my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression says "find a quote zero or more times ;)

Use that:

```
text = text.replace(/<a href="([^"]*)"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/gim, "[$3]($1)");
```

Comment: OUCH... updated the code, try again... now group 1 matches all chars but the quote itself ;)

Comment: I added non-greedy matching so that the expression still works if there is more than one URL in `text`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery solution:

```
var text_html_string = '<a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a>';
$(text_html_string).attr('href'); // http://www.example.com
$(text_html_string).text(); // Example
```

**edit** without jQuery

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a>';
d.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href; // http://www.example.com
```

Comment: I don't want to add a 237kb behemoth to a 4kb userscript.

Comment: Look at Zeptojs then. It is a **seriously** lightweight jquery alternative without as many bells and whistles.

Comment: For the sake of a simple RegEx change, it's definitely overkill to integrate any library (did I mention I hate frameworks? `:p`)

Comment: Alright how about that. I updated with a native javascript alternative that won't break every time your html changes.

Comment: That's actually pretty nice. Why I hadn't thought of this, I don't know. Good job!

Comment: creating one or two DOM objects for subtracting a portion of a string? O.K. it works but elegant it is not ;)

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach I actually think this is a better solution, since it will always work, regardless of which attributes a URL has. I accepted your answer though, since it's directly fixes the RegEx problem, and I know which attributes this URL will have.

Comment: I just didn't want to give the Y part of this X-Y Problem any legitimacy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1253312

Comment: <a[^>]*href="([^"]*)"[^>]*>(.*)<\/a> works in all cases, too.

Comment: It never hits the DOM. always stays in memory and doesn't cause a re-render. Actually pretty cheap operation.

Comment: Wasn't meant that it causes a rerender, as you say it will never get added to the model. But **pretty cheap** is not the cheapest ;) So I always try to omit object creation when not needed (I come from Java). But thinking twice, it could have a lesser impact in cause of the prototyping used in javascript... on that I will take a closer look by time.